# Can I follow Islam and still be close friends to unbelievers?

Tags: kuffar, friendship

Can I follow Islam and still be close friends to unbelievers?

> O ye who believe! Take not for friends unbelievers rather than believers: Do ye wish to offer Allah an open proof against yourselves? (4:144)
>
> O ye who believe! Take not the Jews and the Christians for friends.
>   They are friends one to another. He among you who taketh them for
>   friends is (one) of them. Lo! Allah guideth not wrongdoing folk.
>   (5:51)

> The Misbeliever is a helper (of Evil), against his own Lord! (25:55)

> O ye who believe! Fight those of the disbelievers who are near to you,
>   and let them find harshness in you, and know that Allah is with those
>   who keep their duty. (9:123)

Comment: possible dublicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21833/why-we-shouldnt-take-non-muslims-as-a-friend and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/225/is-it-haraam-to-have-non-muslim-friends

Comment: I didn't down-vote; but I'd hesitate to go for simple readings for complex terms.

Comment: See also: "[Implication of verse 28 from Surah Al-Imran 3:28](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8098/9123)"

Answer (score 4):

Go back to sura 5 aya 5. and sura 60 aya 8.

If you are allowed to marry a non believer why it is haram to be a friend with. The translation you paste is not correct the word in quran is أولياء not أصدقاء you are not allowed to be a friend with someone who affect your beliefs and your Islam.

Comment: Would you mind glossing the Arabic with the English equivalent or nearest in meaning? Thanks.

Comment: I only ask, as I have only basic Arabic, and I'm curious as to the meanings of the two words.

Comment: Allies equivalent to أولياء, friends is equivalent to أصدقاء, allies was the word mentioned in the verse. There is a big difference between an ally and a friend.

Comment: I searched for a word at the end I found what Abdul rahman said.  Allies is the closest word to أولياء . Reference is a translation of the quran from Quran android application.

Comment: I thought: great! problem solved. Then I actually read the suras. If this is all you can come up with, then this is really really sad.  Because this is really nothing. 5:5 basically states that you can marry people from the book. That does NOT include atheists, hindus or buddhists. This only applies men marrying the 'merchandise' of a woman. Not applying to muslim woman -> christian man.  60:8 states you should be righteous. to non-believers. Well buying a product from a non-believer for 5 dollars and actually paying 5 dollars is one thing. Being friends with one is something else.