# I had a Christian friend

Tags: quran, hadith, christianity, friendship, thinking

I had a Christian friend, we have been together some years now.

I now come across this verses of the Qur'an that says

“You (O Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم) will not find any people who believe in Allaah and the Last Day, making friendship with those who oppose Allaah and His Messenger (Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم), even though they were their fathers or their sons or their brothers or their kindred (people)”

[al-Mujaadilah 58:22]

And also in Qur'an Allah said again that

“Let not believers take disbelievers as allies, rather than believers. And whoever [of you] does that has nothing with Allah, except when taking precaution against them in prudence. And Allah warns you of Himself, and to Allah is the [final] destination.”

Surah Ali 'Imran [3:28]

Now I don't know what to do with my friend

Comment: Where is the hadith?

Comment: These quotes are from the qur'an and I pretty sure that they already have been addressed on the site.

Comment: See for example [Can i follow Islam and still be close friend to unbelievers?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29099/can-i-follow-islam-and-still-be-close-friends-to-unbelievers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the prophet uncle Abu Taleb! He died as a mushrik not even Christianity! Do the prophet love him absolutely yes. but he hated his shirk and the year where his uncle and his wife died we call it sad year عام الحزن

There are more evidences that Sahaba loves their mushirk families but hates there shirk as the request from Abu baker for the prophet to guide his father!

Translating the ayah should include more meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Al-Mumtahanah 60:8

لَّا يَنْهَىٰكُمُ ٱللَّهُ عَنِ ٱلَّذِينَ لَمْ يُقَٰتِلُوكُمْ فِى ٱلدِّينِ وَلَمْ يُخْرِجُوكُم مِّن دِيَٰرِكُمْ أَن تَبَرُّوهُمْ وَتُقْسِطُوٓا۟ إِلَيْهِمْۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ يُحِبُّ ٱلْمُقْسِطِينَ

Allah does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of religion and do not expel you from your homes -  from being righteous toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, Allah loves those who act justly.

Al-Mumtahanah 60:9

إِنَّمَا يَنْهَىٰكُمُ ٱللَّهُ عَنِ ٱلَّذِينَ قَٰتَلُوكُمْ فِى ٱلدِّينِ وَأَخْرَجُوكُم مِّن دِيَٰرِكُمْ وَظَٰهَرُوا۟ عَلَىٰٓ إِخْرَاجِكُمْ أَن تَوَلَّوْهُمْۚ وَمَن يَتَوَلَّهُمْ فَأُو۟لَٰٓئِكَ هُمُ ٱلظَّٰلِمُونَ

Allah only forbids you from those who fight you because of religion and expel you from your homes and aid in your expulsion -  [forbids] that you make allies of them. And whoever makes allies of them, then it is those who are the wrongdoers.

This answers for itself